# Cookies are not sent with requests

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I set the following cookie. `token` is a generated jwt token.

```
HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("authorization",
             tokenhandler.WriteToken(token), new CookieOptions()
             {
                 Path = "/",
                 HttpOnly = true,
                 Secure = true,
                 SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax,
                 Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1)
             }) ;
```

when I make calls after being having that cookie set up. I still get 401 unathorized. Arent cookies always automatically sent in the header?

Comment: JWT tokens are sent in headers with **Authorization** key. Why are you using cookies for that?

Comment: At first I straight up sent them in my calls. `axios.interceptors.request.use(config => 
 config.headers.authorization = 'Bearer ' + MyJWTtokenFromServer;
              return config;
           }` but i dont want it to be visible to other potential injected js files

Comment: authentication cookies can be auto-processed by cookie authentication handler but what you set for your cookies is a custom data, you need a custom handler to handle that. Basically, the handler need to extract the token from the request header and try parsing back the authentication ticket, validate it before successfully authenticated.

Comment: is saving it in axios.interceptors a bad practice? I tried accessing it via console and it didnt return a value

Comment: @KingKing i got it now but how can I add the Authentication key with its value to every request after login? people say using httponly cookies are the way to go but that would mean i should make my own authentication handler correct?

Comment: I don't think you need to write your own authentication scheme, looks like you can use the `JwtBearer` scheme. It does not support reading the token from cookies by default, as implemented here https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/a24aed7e5459acc1417a0e490a80e0472d498b2b/src/Security/Authentication/JwtBearer/src/JwtBearerHandler.cs - But you can see it provides you a chance to set the `Token` in the callback `JwtBearerOptions.Events.OnMessageReceived`. There you can read the token from cookies and set to `MessageReceivedContext.Token` manually.